# Have a problem with redirecting a site ot another Subdomain in Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp

I Have done a site but want to redirect it to another subdomain in other language.The site is done in CAKE PHP,so the problem i am facing is I have given the href to subdomain.But the URL is concatenated with the variable 'url' set in the config.php file of Cake Php.That's the reason why it's throwing error.
Please suggest me how can I do this stuff.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question is unclear. Please provide more solid details and possibly some code to better explain your problem.

Comment: the site is in 2 different languages.English and french. The site in English is on the main domain and french on the subdomain.
I have just given a <a href="www.fr.subDomain.com/app/webroot">.
But when I click on the link this is the resulting URl i am getting
"www.mainDomain.com/app/webroot/www.fr.subDomain.com/app/webroot"
I am guessing this b'coz of the config file's variable which have
"url" => "www.mainDomain.com/app/webroot".
I think it is concatenated with it.Please help me out to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob's got it right.

Don't forget the 'http://' part of that link or the browser will interpret it as a relative link.

If your domain is www.exmaple.com
`<a href="/app/webroot">` is exactly the same as `<a href="http://www.example.com/app/webroot">`
The first is a relative link. The second is an absolute link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're providing what appears to be a relative URI. The current path is prepended to that value. Using your anchor tag from the comment above, it should look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.fr.subDomain.com/app/webroot">
```